# What does "aapt feature to compile resources" means?

Tags: android, adt, aapt

A new version of the [eclipse adt plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) has been released recently.

According to [Tor Norbye's post on Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/116539451797396019960/posts/QZ1Cahr8q92) it has a

> new aapt feature to compile resources.

What does this means ? 
Is it possible to package resources in a jar now ?
Does it changes something for library projects ?
Can someone explain what this new aapt feature does ?

I searched in the [ADT change log](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html) and on the [Android Tools Website](http://tools.android.com/recent) without finding any explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing this line was a small mistake. (this was from an internal changelog and was mistakenly copied in Tor's post).

This feature has not actually been released yet (it'll be part of the next update of the platform-tools component).

It is also not a user-facing feature that you shouldn't worry about.

It's a new option in aapt to process a single png (similar to the current "aapt crunch ..." command that does the same on all png files found in the res folder).

It is used by the new build system based on Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

aapt (Android Asset Packaging Tool) compiles the resources. In the comments on Google+, Tor Norbye did not have direct knowledge.  It may be internal revisions since the external feature set seems similar.